# Java: improve if/else conditions

Tags: java

I have a table like this:

```
id  detail
1    text1
2    text2
3    text3
4    text4
5    text5
6    text6
```

I need to create an array that includes some of these values from database, something like this:

```
if ({"Volvo", "BMW", "Ford", "Mazda"}.contains(name)) {
       if(code.equals("10")) {
          String[]detailList = {"text1"};
       } else if(code.equals("20")) {
          String[]detailList = {"text2", "text3"};
       } else if(code.equals("30")) {
          String[]detailList = {"text1", "text3"};
       }
 } else if ({"Ferrari", "Mercedes", "Toyota", "Hyundai"}.contains(name)) {
       if(code.equals("10")) {
          String[]detailList = {"text4"};
       } else if(code.equals("20")) {
          String[]detailList = {"text5", "text6"};
       } else if(code.equals("30")) {
          String[]detailList = {"text4", "text5"};
       }
  }
```

Is there a better way to improve it? Thanks very much.

Comment: You can create two hashmaps and add the String as a key (10, 20, 30) and for each key use a String[] value (text4, {text5, text6}, {text 4, text5}. Then you can change the multiple if statements to check if the code exists within the hashmap and then to assign the details list to the value of the key from the hashmap

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for the ternary-operator:

```
String[] detailList = code.equals("10") ? {"text4"} : 
                     (code.equals("20") ? {"text2", "text3"}:
                     (code.equals("30") ? {"text1", "text3"}:
                     null)) ; //TODO Exception Handling
```